# Rabbit MQ count messages by tag or some property

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I have a rabbit MQ service, multiple apps that publish messages and multiple apps that consume messages. Let's say that there is a list of message types (totally custom, has nothing to do with MQ). I'd like to check the current state of queue to see are there any messages still in a queue that are of a certain type. List of types is not final and can be too large to create a channel for every of them.

So, is it possible to tag a message (with a string that describes the type) when publishing to MQ and later count messages in a queue that has that tag? I'm using .NET libraries.

Comment: AMPQ/RabbitMQ support message headers for storing arbitrary data. You could use those to 'tag' mesages. But where and when do you want to count these messages? Will they be consumed by a consumer you want to do the counting?

Comment: That'll be an issue probably. I'd like to count those before consuming.

Comment: Count where? While sitting in a queue on the RabbitMQ server?

Comment: Well, QueueDeclareOk class has a MessageCount property. So, I was thinking if it is possible to use rabbit MQ libraries to query an MQ service for the count of the messages with certain tag.

Comment: Could please [edit] your question and tell us a little bit about the background of this question? Why do you want to count the unconsumed messages?

Comment: I just edited, thanks.